# Google Analytics sdk creates issue in Xcode 6.3

Tags: ios, ios7, google-analytics, xcode6.3

I am using Google Analytics (version 3.15) for iOS app. my app also supports iOS 7 devices. So whenever I am trying to build the app using xcode 6.3 I am gettinbg below kind of errors,

```
/Volumes/Projects/Projects/inMyDIARY 5.0/inmyDIARY/inmyDIARY/libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(TAGHit.o)
    /Volumes/Projects/Projects/inMyDIARY 5.0/inmyDIARY/inmyDIARY/libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(TAGPValueHash.o)
ld: 226 duplicate symbols for architecture x86_64
```

can anyone have idea how to resolve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I read some details about Google Analytics iOS SDK on official website and I have seen this

> As of version 3.14 Google Analytics supports bitcode, which may cause compiler errors under Xcode 6. If you are still using Xcode 6 consider downloading v3.13.

Apart from that if you want simply want to ignore dependcy related Google Analytics using `Cocoapods`.

You can also go through official link [link](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ios/v3/sdk-download#download_sdk) for more details.